# For loop generator that prints a composite number

Tags: java, for-loop, methods

I want my isPrimeNumber function to return a null (so it will not print any of the numbers in the isPrimeNumber function), but methods apparently cannot return null. I want the for loop to gloss over the numbers that print and the prime number function and print numbers that are not in the prime number function and one, i.e. the composite number. Here is what my code looks like:

```
//prints all composite numbers
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       for(int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
       {
         if (isPrimeNumber(i))
         {
             return null;

         }else{
             System.out.println(i);
         }
       }
    }


    public static boolean isPrimeNumber(int i) {
        int factors = 0;
        int j = 1;

        while(j <= i)
        {
            if(i % j == 0)
            {
                factors++;
            }
            j++;
        }
        return (factors == 2);
  }


}
```

The else statement in the main function is supposed to print all the numbers between 1 and 10000 that are composite. How would I fixed this ?

Answer (score 3):

Don't `return null` when you find a prime number. Yyou can't return a value from a method with a `void` return type, but even if this code did pass compilation, you wouldn't want to leave the method when you detect a prime number.

Change the condition from

```
     if (isPrimeNumber(i)) {
         return null;
     } else {
         System.out.println(i);
     }
```

to

```
     if (!isPrimeNumber(i)) {
         System.out.println(i);
     }
```